# Form Submit Not Caught By Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I am trying to catch the submit of an HTML form (rendered by Django) and process it using ajax, rather than redirecting to a new page, however the javascript function never seems to be called. Here is my rendered html:

```
<form action="" id="id_create_review" method="post">

<div id="div_id_session" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_session" class="control-label ">
        Session
    </label>
    <div class="controls ">
        <select class="select form-control" id="id_session" name="session">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Rocky Balboa Boxing Club</option>
            <option value="2">All about the Box...ing</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="div_id_rating" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_rating" class="control-label  requiredField">
        Rating<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls ">
        <select class="select form-control" id="id_rating" name="rating">
            <option value="0.0">0.0</option>
            <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
            <option value="1.0">1.0</option>
            <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
            <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
            <option value="2.5" selected="selected">2.5</option>
            <option value="3.0">3.0</option>
            <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
            <option value="4.0">4.0</option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
            <option value="5.0">5.0</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="div_id_comments" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_comments" class="control-label  requiredField">
                    Comments<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls ">
        <textarea class="textarea form-control" cols="40" id="id_comments" name="comments" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div id="div_id_would_recommend" class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_would_recommend" class="">
            <input checked="checked" class="checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_would_recommend" name="would_recommend" type="checkbox">
            Would recommend
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div id="div_id_anonymous" class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_anonymous" class="">
            <input checked="checked" class="checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_anonymous" name="anonymous" type="checkbox">
             Anonymous
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Review" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-submit"> 
</div>

</form>
```

Here is my javascript at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_create_review').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        console.log('Yeah, no?');
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#success_div').html(response); // update the DIV
            },
            error: function(e, x, r) { // on error..
                $('#error_div').html(e); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

So what is happening is that I am getting a 403 Error because of CSRF protection failing. I have some javascript that should be preventing this 403 error if the request was made with ajax, I am also not seeing the "Yeah, no?" logged to the console, so I figured that the form must be being submitted via standard Http.

Maybe my problem is that the form is being processed by the javascript, but that the ajax request is still causing the 403 error? But then why wouldn't I see the console log in my JS?

And if the problem is that my ajax request is causing the 403 error, why is my protection code not working to send a csrf token? I can't say that I 100% understand all of it... I mostly grabbed it from an online tutorial of processing ajax requests with django. Here is the code:

```
<script>
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

/*
The functions below will create a header with csrftoken
*/

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your script? Code looks plausible... Most likely something unrelated to code you've shown (like duplicate ID or syntax errors in script )...

Comment: I created this **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vfcw8fab/)** . Code seems to be working fine, check console.

Comment: check your jQuery library script tag

Comment: if you're not getting the initial console.log("yeah, no"), then jQuery is not being loaded. Are you able to console.log() anything right after $(document).ready() ? I would also check your Web Developer Tools to see that all your linked scripts or external files are being loaded. Some firewalls can block certain connections

Comment: Yeah, the jQuery is being loaded. I have other jQuery effects on the page that are working just fine, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who offered solutions. I ended up solving the issue by moving my script inside the included django template that the form was in.

I have a main django template which includes a smaller django template using the {% include %} tag, and the form is in this included template. Originally I had my javascript to catch the submission of the form at the bottom of the main template. I figured this would be fine because the templates would all be rendered into one big HTML file anyways, so it wouldn't really make a difference which code was in which template, but apparently it did... As soon as I moved my script into my small, included template the problem went away. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: It's possible the script was simply not in the right section of the included file. What block was it contained in?

Comment: Also, if you put your Javascript into a .js file you can include it using {% static "path/to/file/in/static/files" %} and that allows you to keep the contents in its own file.

Comment: Actually the view that contained the form was a view rendered from an ajax request sent from the included template. But still, it's all one HTML document after the rendering, right? And my scripts are just before the close of the body tag, in a block I have called `{% block extra_scripts %}`

Comment: From: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/

The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means that there is no shared state between included templates – each include is a completely independent rendering process.

edit: guess that solves everything.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_create_review').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        console.log('Yeah, no?');
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        var postdata = $(this).serializeArray();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(url , postdata, function(){
            //
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a hidden input field and put into its value the csrftoken...something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{% csrf_token %}">
```

That should be enough if your error is being caused by the csrf protection.

Answer (score 0):

Django Docs [on include template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/)

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means that there is no shared state between included templates – each include is a completely independent rendering process.

That's why you had to move the script. I wasn't previously aware of that.

Comment: Shouldn't that only affect how the templates are rendered on the server though? Once it gets to my browser wouldn't it all be seen as the same HTML, and thus all javascript should act the same on any part as if it were all in the same template on the server?

Comment: true. perhaps I was just quick to assume given I seem to recall a similar thing happening to me. And it just seemed to magically explain it away. On a side note, how was the original template laid out? The one the form is being included on? can you post that?